# Flex. ROLL-OVER color in advanced data grid header

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

How can I change the rollover color of `AdvancedDataGrid` 's header? It's light-blue by default.

I tried using a `HeaderRenderer`, but it does not help. There is a 2 pixel color border on the top and bottom of the header that I can't control.

Thanks
Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `rollOverColor` that is used in header:

   <mx:AdvancedDataGrid rollOverColor="0xFFCC00"/>
2. Create a subclass of `AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer` and override `updateDisplayList()` to add the required visual logic to use it as `headerRenderer`.

P.S: `AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer` source code is available by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + T` in Flash Builder and typing the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jcraane.blogspot.com/2009/10/flex-how-to-create-different-rollover.html